# Which package provides kmod-zstd on openSUSE 15.2?

Tags: linux, kernel, opensuse

I am running openSUSE 15.2, but with a [newer stable kernel](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Kernel:/stable/standard/) in order to have a driver for the RTL8125 network interface.

Currently, I am on kernel-default-5.13.7-1.1.gb1bb2c4.x86_64 and I would like to update to the newer package providing 5.15. However, the update is denied because

> nothing provides 'kmod-zstd'

```
$ sudo zypper in kernel-default-5.15.7-1.1.gb92986a
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides 'kmod-zstd' needed by the to be installed kernel-default-5.15.7-1.1.gb92986a.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install kernel-default-5.15.7-1.1.gb92986a.x86_64
 Solution 2: break kernel-default-5.15.7-1.1.gb92986a.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c/d/?] (c): c
```

Which package do I have to install or to update to enable support for 'kmod-zstd'?

Comment: Examples : `kmod-29-150400.3.4.x86_64` provides kmod-zstd . .... `kmod-29-4.12.1.x86_64` provides kmod-zstd . ... Ref. http://rpm.pbone.net/ → openSUSE Leap 15, OpenSuSE.